# localhost redirected you too many times in Django

Tags: python, django

I am using `user_passes_test` decorator. and the view `blog_update_view` redirects only if there is a post request. Then why am I getting so many redirects when a non admin user tries to update the blog? I

```
def check_admin(user):
   return user.is_superuser

@user_passes_test(check_admin)
def blog_update_view(request, blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=blog)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Blog updated!!')
            return redirect(blog.get_absolute_url())

    form = BlogForm(instance=blog)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'blog': blog,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'blogs/blog_update.html', context)
```

My `urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'blogs'
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/',
         blog_category_view, name='blog_category'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/',
         blog_tag_view, name='blog_tag'),
    path('new/', blog_create_view, name='blog_create'),
    path('<slug:blog_slug>/update/', blog_update_view, name='blog_update'),
    path('like/', like_blog_view, name='like_blog'),
    path('search/', SearchBlog.as_view(), name='search_blog'),
    path('<slug:blog_slug>/', blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    path('', blog_home_view, name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) has `login_url` parameter which takes an url where the user is redirected in case the function returns `False` (which is this case). By default this value is `settings.LOGIN_URL`. But there's no point of showing a login form to user who's logged in already, so the view redirects the user further to `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

to avoid this behaviour:

- either provide different value for `login_url` parameter in `user_passes_test()`, so there's one fewer redirects
- prevent non-admins accessing this form/functionality in first place by hiding the form / submit button in template?

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <form> ... <input type="submit" value="update blogpost"> ... </form>
{% else %}
    <div class="view-only"> {{ blogpost }} </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: do you have any solution for my problem? I need this view for super user only?

Comment: dont provide that form to non-super users then? Updated answer

Comment: I did that in template, but how do I prevent it in views? someone with technical knowledge can add `/update/` and can get access to update blog easily. I tried `if not request.user == request.is_superuser: return PermissionDenied` it didnt' work either.